# Masked text box search and sql query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, t-sql, maskedtextbox

I have a masked textbox in c# winform.

The masking would be like

```
 - (two numbers on the front and 4 number on the right after the dash).

for ex: 12-3456
```

There are more permutations like

```
   - (3 spaces on the front and 5 on the right)

for ex: 123-34567
```

> When a user types 123-34567, the select sql query should return only
>
> 123-34567
>
> When a user types 12-3456, the select sql query should return only
>
> 12-3456
>
> When a user types   -, the select sql query should return
>   only
>
> 12-3456 (ie. two spaces typed)
>
> When a user types    -, the select sql query should
>   return only
>
> 123-34567 (ie. three spaces typed)
>
> In other words, a user can search without entering anything and have
>   only mask enabled text box and
>   search(empty - empty) - only dash mask , type number(s) on the
>   mask and search (for ex: 12- ).

The query am using is

```
select column1,column2 from table1 where column2 like '%__-%';
```

(the underscores are dymanically calculated) and how do i get this in any other optimum approach (say like in a single query) ?

Consider this table1 and having a column "MaskedInfo" in the database.

```
Table1:

MaskedInfo  

1234567
12-34567
123-4567
123-45678
```

> User can type anything to search like 12-34567 or 123-4567 or simply
>   1234567 and if the text box is empy load everything in the result.

Comment: Do you wanna check the samples in your question? They dont seem to be following your logic. Or mebbe I do not understand the connection between what the user types in the masked textbox and how it is stored in SQL Server!

Comment: Ah, this textbox is for search! We needed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the first %, you're changing the spaces int he user input for underscores, there you're right but the first % will get you results with something before the underscores, 
so

```
like '%__-%'  //(two underscores)
```

will get anything that has two or more digits before the -,

```
like '%___-%'  //(three underscores)
```

will get anything that has three or more digits before the -

removing the first % will get the result that have exactly as many digits as underscores

Comment: Yes, can this be done in more optimum way, say like in a single query?

Comment: The pseudocode will be if two spaces before dash and no numbers or letters, then '%___-%' like this, I am not able to get it in a single query, there is CASE WHEN, but am not getting it in a single select query.

Comment: maybe you can change the string used in the like for a parameter in the command
    select column1, column2 from table where column2 like @Param
and just pass the value of the textbox as the parameter
    sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Param",textbox.text.replace(" ","_")+"-%"));

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use charindex:

WHERE (@search = '' OR charindex('-', @search) = charindex('-', column2))